# I need to translate a dynamic variable in angular-translate

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-translate

Suppose this is the provided json file for the translations.

```
{
  "TRANSLATION_ID": "{{username}} is logged in.",
  "ANOTHER_ID": "PascalPrecht"
}
```

And this is the js code:

```
let expressionToTranslate = "TRANSLATION_ID"
let username = "ANOTHER_ID"
```

If we do the following:

```
{{expressionToTranslate | translate:username}}
```

We will get "ANOTHER_ID is logged in".

How is it possible to actually translate the variable in order to be able to have "PascalPrecht is logged in"?

Comment: There is a typo, it should be:
{{expressionToTranslate | translate:{username:username} }}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested in solving this problem, I solved it with the following:

inside the controller/component I used

```
 $translate(username).then((paragraph)=>{
 username = paragraph
});
```

Now username became 'PascalPrecht'. And then rendered

```
{{expressionToTranslate | translate:{username: username}}}
```

in the view.

Comment: This solution is practical and to complete it, I have to say you can use general variable in $scope for instance:

       $translate($scope.username).then((paragraph)=>{
            $scope.username = paragraph
        });

Answer (score 0):

It expects an object where the keys are the same as the expression in your language config:

```
{{expressionToTranslate | translate:{username: username}}}
```

Comment: That was a typo, I don't know if I can edit the question. Consider it
{{expressionToTranslate | translate:{username:username} }}
What would the solution be?

Comment: Please reread the question, my problem is not with the angular-translate implementation, my problem is translating a dynamic variable. So what I currently get is "ANOTHER_ID is logged in" since username = "ANOTHER_ID", I would like to get "PascalPrecht is logged in", which means translating the username's value (ANOTHER_ID) to its proper value "PascalPrecht"

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
let username = "ANOTHER_ID";
```

> "TRANSLATION_ID": `${username} is logged in.``

Comment: What does ${username} mean then?

Comment: You can pass on this way a variable in a string in JS

Comment: Yes I know that, but your result is actually the same result that I have. It will be:

"ANOTHER_ID is logged in".